# Flutter Firebase optional or Filter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Since `firestore 4.5.0` there are `or`-filters. But you have to give **at least 2** filters which kind of makes sense for an `or` function.

In my case, I have one `filter` that should always be there but the other one is optional. For now I am working this workaround where the second filter is simply the same as the first filter if the condition si not met:

```
var wishlistCollectionRef = firestoreInstance
    .collection(BackendKeys.user.allUsers)
    .doc(uid)
    .collection(BackendKeys.wishlist.wishlists)
    .where(
      Filter.or(
        Filter(BackendKeys.wishlist.wishlistVisiblity,
            isEqualTo: WishlistVisibility.public.name),
        Filter(BackendKeys.wishlist.wishlistVisiblity,
            isEqualTo: status == FriendRequestStatus.accepted
                ? WishlistVisibility.friends.name
                : WishlistVisibility.public.name),
      ),
    );
```

This is obviously not very clean. Is there an offical way to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: "you have to give at least 2 filters " Huh? Does the SDK give an error message is you specify only one condition? Can you share that error message, as I might want to challenge (or as least ask about) the reason for that API design?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it's the function itself that expects two filters: `2 positional arguments expected by 'or', but 1 found.`

Comment: Hmmm... yeah, I see how the declaration [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Filter/or.html) would lead to that error. I guess without API changes, I'd probably pre-build an arrray of the conditions outside of this variable declaration, so that you can wrap them in an `or` if there's more than 1.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry I don’t quite follow you. How would I change my code to your suggestion?

Comment: Frank is saying that you should have a way to know if you have the two or just one filter active and use it in your where clause as follow: `.where(oneFilter ? you filter : Filter.or( cond with both filters ))`

Comment: @ColinLazarini oh right, ok. That makes things cleaner. Thanks the both of you :)